# Browser adds $metadata to OData call

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

I try to consume [OData service](http://services.odata.org/V3/(S(ql0iexfh2tyudc5p4qhx5gdf))/OData/OData.svc) using SAPUI5 framework.

When I tested my app on localhost, I did as follows:

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel("proxy/http/services.odata.org/V3/(S(ql0iexfh2tyudc5p4qhx5gdf))/OData/OData.svc");
```

and it worked fine.

But when I uploaded the app to the cloud platform, I got the following error:

```
GET https://<accountname>.hana.ondemand.com/OData/proxy/http/services.odata.org/V3/(S(ql0iexfh2tyudc5p4qhx5gdf))/OData/OData.svc/$metadata 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

If I use `https://services.odata.org/...` in OData Model's declaration, I get another error:

```
OPTIONS https://services.odata.org/V3/(S(ql0iexfh2tyudc5p4qhx5gdf))/OData/OData.svc/$metadata 501 (Not Implemented)
```

It looks like it adds for some reason `$metadata` to the call and the call doesn't work.

How should I declare the OData service's URI to get it work from the cloud platform?

Comment: Might be a silly question, but does your cloud platform explicitly support OData? Because it looks like to me that it doesn't.

Comment: It's SAP HANA Cloud Platform and it supports OData. What may be the problem - is that I do something wrong..

Comment: this is what you should get if you call $metadata itself without the proxyServlet in front: http://services.odata.org/V3/(S(ql0iexfh2tyudc5p4qhx5gdf))/OData/OData.svc/$metadata

Comment: $metadata is just the description file of an OData-Service like WSDL for SOAP

Comment: to test if your proxyServlet is working correctly... try to call another page with it like so: https://<accountname>.hana.ondemand.com/OData/proxy/http/google.de

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I didn't have properly defined destination.

I'm still looking for a solution about how to add destination using Eclipse IDE, but this particular question may be considered answered.